# How to force a docker container to run and execute a script that requires user interaction?

Tags: shell, docker, tomcat, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker image built from a Dockerfile. The script in the entrypoint starts Tomcat server. When the script starts it asks for confirmation .

If interactive shell is enabled, then the script would be waiting and Tomcat server would never start. Then I have to manually execute the start-pentaho.sh script from inside the container.

If interactive shell is disabled, then the tomcat would start. But then the container would get an exited state.

Is there a way to get my container running without executing start-pentaho manually?

Here is a MWE:

The pentaho zip file was downlaoded from:

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Pentaho%208.1/server/pentaho-server-ce-8.1.0.0-365.zip/download
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
COPY ./pentaho-server-ce-8.1.0.0-365.zip /pentaho/pentaho-server-ce-8.1.zip
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install unzip && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
RUN unzip /pentaho/pentaho-server-ce-8.1.zip
ENTRYPOINT ["/pentaho-server/start-pentaho.sh"]
```

building the image using :

```
docker build -t mtleis/pentaho:v1.0 .
```

docker-compose.yml

```
pentaho:
        image:  mtleis/pentaho:v1.0
        ports:
            - "8081:8080"
# The following two lines are needed to keep the container running. However Tomcat will never start. Disabling them, Tomcat would start but the container get an exited state. 
#        stdin_open: true
#        tty: true
```

Run docker-compose:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Check container logs:

```
docker logs id

WARNING: Using java from path
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Pentaho BI Platform now contains a version checker that will notify you
when newer versions of the software are available. The version checker is enabled by default.
For information on what the version checker does, why it is beneficial, and how it works see:
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/Version+Checker
Press Enter to continue, or type cancel or Ctrl-C to prevent the server from starting.
You will only be prompted once with this question.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK]:
Tomcat started.
```

However if the 2 lines in dokcer-compose.yml are enabled:

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

the logs shows that Tomcat is not started yet:

```
WARNING: Using java from path
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Pentaho BI Platform now contains a version checker that will notify you
when newer versions of the software are available. The version checker is enabled by default.
For information on what the version checker does, why it is beneficial, and how it works see:
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/Version+Checker
Press Enter to continue, or type cancel or Ctrl-C to prevent the server from starting.
You will only be prompted once with this question.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK]:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After understanding how the containers are behaving. The answer was is remove the user prompt and to add command `tail -f /dev/null` to the entrypoint shell file to keep the container alive.

The user prompt was what keeping the container running. This prompt was located in `userprompt.sh` file. The prompt `read choice` was removed. Now the script will continue its execution and at the end it will exit. Even running the container using command

```
docker run -itd imagename /bin/bash
```

The container would exit. This is still something I do not understand yet.

As a workaround, I finally edited the start-pentaho.sh script by adding `tail -f /dev/null` to the end. Now the container is running.

Here is the new Dockerfile used to build pentaho image:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:latest
COPY ./pentaho-server-ce-8.1.zip /pentaho/pentaho-server-ce-8.1.zip
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install unzip && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
RUN unzip /pentaho/pentaho-server-ce-8.1.zip -d /pentaho
# copy a modified copy of userprompt.sh file
COPY ./promptuser.sh /pentaho/pentaho-server/promptuser.sh
# copy a modified copy of the entrypoint script
COPY ./start-pentaho.sh /pentaho/pentaho-server/start-pentaho.sh
RUN chmod +x /pentaho/pentaho-server/start-pentaho.sh
ENTRYPOINT /pentaho/pentaho-server/start-pentaho.sh
```